# Getting radio button value in while loop

Tags: php

I'm doing a simple examination program using PHP.

Here is my code for taking the quiz, it's still in testing so don't mind the design.

This is the session for the person who is taking the quiz (no problem here):

```
<?php
session_start ();
$_SESSION['username'];
?>
<div id="wrap">
    <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="myproject"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="q_quiz"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // get value of id that sent from address bar 
    $id=$_GET['q_id'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE q_id='$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    ?>

    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="100%" frame="box" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><h3>Quiz Info : </h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><strong>Quiz Name : </strong><?php echo $rows['q_name']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <font size="6">
    <div style="font-weight: bold" id="quiz-time-left"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var max_time = <?php echo $rows['q_time'] ?>;
    var c_seconds  = 0;
    var total_seconds =60*max_time;
    max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
    document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
    function init(){
        document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
        setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
    }
    function CheckTime(){
        document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds' ;
        if(total_seconds <=0){
            setTimeout('document.quiz.submit()',1);
        } else {
            total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
            max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
            c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
            setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
        }
    }
    init();
    </script>
    </font>

    <form action="result.php" method="post">
    <?php
    $score = 0;
    $tbl_name2="a_quiz"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE q_id='$id'";
    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        $q_question = $rows['q_question'];
        ?>
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <tr style='overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-word;'>
                            <input type="text" name="q_id" value="<?php echo $rows['q_id'];?>">
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>Question:</strong></td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen" style="max-width: 1000px;"><?php echo $rows['q_question']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>A</strong></td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $q_question; ?>" value="a"><?php echo $rows['a'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>B</strong></td>
                            <td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
                            <td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $q_question; ?>" value="b"><?php echo $rows['b'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>C</strong></td>
                            <td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
                            <td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $q_question; ?>" value="c"><?php echo $rows['c'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>D</strong></td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $q_question; ?>" value="d"><?php echo $rows['d'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }

    $connection=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
    mysql_select_db('thesis');

    $username= $_SESSION['username'];

    $query6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE username='$username'");
    $row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query6);
    $s_id = $row6['id'];
    $name = $row6['name'];
    $email = $row6['email'];
    $position = $row6['position'];
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="s_id" value="<?php echo $s_id ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Answer" class="btn">
    </form>
</div>
```

I provided an image (I inputted two questions, this is the output of the code above):

http://i60.tinypic.com/2lu8doh.jpg

(`2` is the quiz id, no problem on this, `12` near the submit button is the examiner id)

There's no problem in the code above.

My problem starts here. I am only getting the answer of the (examiner/person taking the quiz) of the question number `1` only and I already found my error.

This code below initiates when I click the submit button:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die("Error:".mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("myproject",$con);
}
```

I'm only getting the answer in the question number 1 of the examiner, because of this. It is not a loop so I'm only getting one answer even if theres 2-3 more answers.

```
$stud_id = $_POST['s_id'];
$quiz_id = $_POST['q_id'];
$score = 0;

$tbl_name2="a_quiz"; 
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE q_id='$quiz_id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $q_question=$rows['q_question'];
    $question1 = $rows['answer'];

    echo $q_question;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $question1;
    echo '<br>';
    if(isset($_POST[$q_question])){
        $s_answer = $_POST[$q_question];
        echo $s_answer;
        if ($question1 == $s_answer){
            $score = $score + 1;
        }
    }
}
echo $score;
```

So, for example, I got question 1 and question 2 and I selected the correct answer in number 1 I'm getting and `$score++` but when my answer in question 2 is also correct is doesn't do `$score++`.

My problem here is: How can I get the value of radio button which I outputted them in while loop? Do I need to do a while loop for the answer too? How?

Comment: The key to answering your question is the `<form>` that is submitted when user finishes test. It contains the users' answers, and the field names, for each question. In order to show you how to loop through the sets of question/answers, we need to see either the HTML for your form, or the PHP of how you are trying to do it now.

Comment: theres the form kindly check it, check the code with the session

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using each question as name attribute for your radio buttons, which is far from perfect. You might consider add a column to the table 'a_quiz' with a **unique** namespace for each question with no space in it (for instance question-one, question-two...) and call this column 'namespace'.

After this is done, you questions loop should look like this:

```
<?php
$score = 0;
$tbl_name2="a_quiz"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE q_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

    $q_question = $rows['q_question'];
    $namespace = $rows['namespace'];

?>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr style='overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-word;'>
    <input type="text" name="q_id" value="<?php echo $rows['q_id'];?>">
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>Question:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen" style="max-width: 1000px;"><?php echo $rows['q_question']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>A</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $namespace; ?>" value="a"><?php echo $rows['a'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>B</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $namespace; ?>" value="b"><?php echo $rows['b'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>C</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $namespace; ?>" value="c"><?php echo $rows['c'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>D</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $namespace; ?>" value="d"><?php echo $rows['d'] ?></td>
</tr>


</table></td>
</tr>
<hr>
</table><br>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Then, for the results part, use this code:

```
$stud_id = (int)$_POST['s_id'];
$quiz_id = (int)$_POST['q_id'];
$score = 0;

$tbl_name2 = "a_quiz"; 

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE q_id='$quiz_id'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

$result = '';

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

    $q_question = $rows['q_question'];
    $question1 = $rows['answer'];
    $namespace = $rows['namespace'];

    $result .= $q_question;
    $result .= <br>;
    $result .= $question1;
    $result .= <br>;

    if(isset($_POST[$namespace])){

        $s_answer = $_POST[$namespace];

        $result .= $s_answer;

        if ($question1 == $s_answer)
            $score++;

    }

}

$result .= $score;

echo $result;

}
?>
```

Comment: ok i will try this, btw what is the purpose of the namespace what should it contain

Comment: Think of it as a variable that will contain which radio button is active. Radio buttons work by sharing the same `name=` "variable" -- that is how only one is made active at a time.